# Joining two tables based on matching two columns

Tags: join, sas, natural-join

I'm trying to join two tables: 
Table A has three columns: State, County, and Count (of Farmer's Markets in said county)
Table B has several columns: State, County, and several data columns (like food access score)

I'm trying to combine them in such a way as to put the Count for each State/County combination (since there are multiple counties with the same name) together with the State and County and data columns from Table B.

I've been banging my head on SAS, trying to get a join to cooperate. I read a few other questions on here, but I can't find where the mistake is in my code.

```
PROC SQL; 
CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY1 
AS 
SELECT FMDV4.State, FMDV4.County, FMDV4.Count, CFSDV1.GROC14, 
CFSDV1.SUPERC14, CFSDV1.CONVS14, CFSDV1.SPECS14, CFSDV1.FOODINSEC_13_15, 
CFSDV1.PCT_LACCESS_POP15, CFSDV1.DIRSALES_FARMS12, CFSDV1.FMRKT16, 
CFSDV1.FOODHUB16, CFSDV1.CSA12, CFSDV1.POVRATE15, CFSDV1.PERPOV10 
    FROM FNLPRJT.CFSDV1 AS CFSDV1
    INNER JOIN FNLPRJT.FMDV4 AS FMDV4 
    ON (( CFSDV1.State = FMDV4.State ) AND ( CFSDV1.County = 
FMDV4.County )); 
QUIT;
```

I also tried a few variants, like:

```
PROC SQL; 
CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY1 
AS 
SELECT FMDV4.State, FMDV4.County, FMDV4.Count, CFSDV1.GROC14, 
CFSDV1.SUPERC14, CFSDV1.CONVS14, CFSDV1.SPECS14, CFSDV1.FOODINSEC_13_15, 
CFSDV1.PCT_LACCESS_POP15, CFSDV1.DIRSALES_FARMS12, CFSDV1.FMRKT16, 
CFSDV1.FOODHUB16, CFSDV1.CSA12, CFSDV1.POVRATE15, CFSDV1.PERPOV10 
    FROM FNLPRJT.CFSDV1 AS CFSDV1
    INNER JOIN FNLPRJT.FMDV4 AS FMDV4 
    ON CFSDV1.State = FMDV4.State 
    WHERE CFSDV1.County = FMDV4.County; 
QUIT;
```

I get a table of 0 rows with the columns as they should be (State, County, Count, ). I'm just missing the dang data! Can anyone please help me find my mistake?

Comment: Check your data. For values to match, the case will need to be exact, ie Hawaii is not equal to HAWAII. And spaces or abbreviations should match. Your code seems correct, so something in your data itself isn't matching for some reason.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) The obvious guess from your unclear "combine" sentence suggests the queries you give. When giving a (base or query result) relation(ship)/association or table, say what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table.

Comment: It was a case issue, as shown by user2239912. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
propcase(CFSDV1.State) = propcase(FMDV4.State)
```

and

```
propcase(CFSDV1.County) = propcase(FMDV4.County);
```

If this doesn't work try character functions like **trim** and **compress** to remove any blanks that might be present in the data.

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Comment: OMG, that worked! So something in the cases didn't match! And now that I look at it, knowing that... I forgot to capitalize my data for County in the first table. ARG! You're a lifesaver.